# Do we need to check for cross-origin on server side?

Tags: webserver, cors

Modern browsers don't allow cross-origin requests - those must be explicitly allowed by CORS headers. But looking at Java back ends like Tomcat/Spring MVC I see that it's possible to [reject requests](https://github.com/quickhack/tomcat/blob/6782a9ffa2f34ba0183361f2b40934309a357034/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java#L254) from other origins on server side.

Since browsers handle this on their end - do we really need to care about it on server side? Well, there are Simple Requests which we do need to take care of, but those can easily be disabled by requiring some custom HTTP header. What about the rest of the cases?

Comment: I've changed the title of your question to match what you were actually asking: It is about detecting cross-origin requests, not about SOP. These are related but still different things.

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to handle them on the backend as they can easily be spoofed.

The concept of CORS is to ensure one resource (say `hacker.com`) cannot access another resource (say `facebook.com`) in the browser unless the accessed resource gives permissions. This is only relevant in the context of a browser as the resources being accessed are cookies, headers and more and thus enforced by the browser to separate these two resources from each other.

By trying to enforce it on the backend, you aren't providing any additional security measures as the browser is the one holding the "sensitive" data. Additionally, the origin header can easily be spoofed.
I assume the settings you see in Tomcat and Spring are just for setting the CORS settings to let the browser know what origin's to allow and what to deny.

Comment: No, I clearly see that they can reject CORS requests: https://github.com/quickhack/tomcat/blob/6782a9ffa2f34ba0183361f2b40934309a357034/src/main/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/CorsFilter.java#L254. In SpringMVC rejection is configurable and is turned off by default.

Comment: Rejecting AJAX requests by rejecting the pre-flights is possible. But where do you see the denial by origin's? I see configuration done for allowed origins but that's for the CROS header for the browser.

Comment: Ah I see now in your edit to the post. Not sure what the login is behind that, once again, the origin can be spoofed anyways.

Comment: Not sure how you can spoof them easily - you'd have to be both in control of the malicious page _and_ be a MIT to change headers that browser sends. And with HTTP2 it's ever harder as headers get encrypted.

Comment: The origin header is not spoofable in the browser.

Comment: @multithr3at3d: Sure it is.  When we're talking about what the browser can do, we are assuming a malicious browser, not a trustworthy browser which happens to be displaying an untrusted site.  Maybe that can be made clearer by calling it an "HTTPS client" not a browser?

Comment: @BenVoigt, do we? If browser is malicious, then nothing can prevent it from sending a CORS request. It can even send requests w/o user involvement once the user is authenticated.

Comment: @BubbleHacker: And that's why the insight in this answer is so valuable.  The browser already has the cookies CORS is designed to protect, so server-side CORS logic can do nothing.

Comment: Irrelevant to the particular scenario, but serves as an example of where this is needed: if you are using WebSockets, you must absolutely check the origin header in the WebSocket upgrade request on the backend, since normal CORS protections do not apply to WebSockets.

Comment: @multithr3at3d for sure, still can easily be spoofed though.

Comment: @BubbleHacker Of course you can set headers to whatever you want in a generic HTTP client or malicious browser. That's irrelevant. In the typical browser CORS context, it is not spoofable, and can be relied on.

Comment: @BenVoigt sometimes an attacker sets up evildoer.com and lures visitors and in this case, the browser will 'not' be malicious and I would think you want to prevent CORS server side in this case or else allow some evil javascript to make requests to an API with a user that has access since he was lured to that website in some fashion(say twitter, etc to the website).

Comment: @BubbleHacker with this new context above, are you sure you are 100% in that "There is no reason to handle them on the backend as they can easily be spoofed". You open up the attack vector I mention and it sounds like the answer below has a link to an article stating the same thing and that attack vector needs to be shut down server-side.  (ie. we may want to change the answer so people start shutting down this attack vector - there are too many damn attack vectors :( ).

Comment: @DeanHiller: In your example, the request never reaches the legitimate server (the browser blocks it), so there is no reason for the legitimate server to have any related logic.  In fact your `evildoer.com` example is identical to the `hacker.com` example already in Bubble's answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt sorry, I mean for a 'simple request' which avoids the options request.  If criteria is met, a simple request is sent and an options preflight is never ever sent.  In this case, if the server does respond, that seems like a security hole.

Comment: @BenVoigt as an attacker, here is how I get the preflight options requesst so the browser sends my CORS request to the server (and server-side 'should' deny my GET/POST request 'I think', right?) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968406/how-to-skip-the-options-preflight-request

Comment: BTW - Honestly trying to figure out if my thinking is wrong here.

Comment: @DeanHiller: That question specifically talks about the need for the protected resource to whitelist the origin with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` because otherwise the request is blocked/stripped of payload by browser CORS protection.

Comment: oh yeah, I guess I forgot he mentioned excluding simple requests which I was wondering about checking server side for those.  thanks @BenVoigt

Answer (score 2):

The cross-origin nature of a request can be of interest on the server-side beyond allowing/disallowing the request for CORS purposes. In particular, you may want to implement a *resource-isolation policy*:

> It is common for resources exposed by a given web application to only be loaded by the application itself, and not by other websites. In such cases, deploying a Resource Isolation Policy based on Fetch Metadata request headers takes little effort, and at the same time protects the application from cross-site attacks.

(source: [Protect your resources from web attacks with Fetch Metadata](https://web.dev/fetch-metadata/))

Comment: This may soften the blow of legitimate browsers being turning into zombies executing a DDOS attack, it doesn't protect your resources from disclosure to an HTTPS client that wants them.

Comment: @BenVoigt I never professed otherwise. An RIP isn't a substitute for authorization. Another important benefit, though, is that it allows you to save bandwidth if third-party Web origins try to load your content.

Comment: OMG, I think this is a perfect case.  I lure user with creds to a target CORS api to my website evildoer.com (user uses chrome of course) and I have a CORS request to an API that user has access to.  The server 'should' deny that CORS request as evildoer.com should not be a whitelisted website.  Thanks @jub0bs.  I think this is a great example as attacker is luring users into an open hole where server just allows all domains on CORS. (I think????)

Comment: @DeanHiller Huh?  No, it is the browser than must deny the CORS request.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I wish I had a forum so I could jump online in real-time and discuss with you...heh.  I posted on the other longer thread above.

Comment: @jub0bs perhaps you can comment on the above thread - comment section as well.  I think fetch metadata solves that issue of course but without fetch meta data, seems like the server should correctly deny 'simple requests' that do not do the options request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to ask why servers have origin checks when it comes to protecting resources and sensitive actions. CORS will prevent the reading of sensitive data by malicious sites, but it will not prevent the posting of data to a server. An important step in added security to mitigate this is the now default same-site policy on cookies across all major browsers. However, security needs redundancies (what if same-site policy is set to lax accident?) and additional server checks are important.

For example, your bank would like to protect your account. If a malicious site tries to call your bank site requesting a withdrawal, the bank server should first check if the Origin header of the request matches the bank's domain (or aby of its whitelisted sites). If not, it should reject the request. Hidden form tokens provide another layer of protection against cross-origin writes. A rest client or curl call can spoof the origin as some comments note, but that doesn't matter because an attacker still needs access to the cookie key which resides in your browser. Back to the browser, CORS policy alone won't secure the server from processing a request as you can see.

Comment: "_CORS will prevent the reading of sensitive data by malicious sites, but it will not prevent the posting of data to a server_" - well, but it will. Browser will not allow sending a cross-domain POST request unless CORS allows this explicitly. "_security needs redundancies (what if same-site policy is set to lax accident?) and additional server checks are important_" - yep, maybe that's the reason. Unfortunately no one seems to know for sure and it's not documented ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I agree partially since most requests are sent with json content these days, but still with the caveat that an OPTION preflight request doesn't apply to simple POST requests (url-encoded etc. form submissions) and these can still go through to the server. It still falls on the server side to maintain some sort of auth.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev _Browser will not allow sending a cross-domain POST request unless CORS allows this explicitly._ Incorrect. Any cross-origin POST submission will result in a request that doesn't participate in the CORS protocol. The client won't be able to read the response, but the request will get sent.